# Should I use fat JAR or not (wrapper on REST API)

Tags: java, rest, architecture

I'm using JAVA to access a REST apis of a 3d party service.
I'm trying to develop a wrapper to the REST api that will handle the authentication and authorization, and in addition, will parse requests/responses.
(this project depends on -  apache httpclient , jackson-core jars, Auth jar).

All the other projects should use the jar above, to access the APIs.

My question is, what is the better approach.
To build the JAR above as a fat jar, with all the dependencies,
or as a regular jar, and add in the consumers, the missing dependencies. (such jackson..)

Thanks!

Comment: it is 100% up to you and bears little to no effect on the things you are trying to achieve. Basically fat jar of Spring Boot for example speeds up development and deployment but it is more of a convenience than anything. Also, these kinds of questions are invite opinion-based answers and therefore offtopic just like a question what is better for backend Java or nodeJs?

Comment: A fat jar as a dependency can result in clashes with actual dependencies of one of your projects. It's usually a good idea to have tools like Maven or Gradle handle the dependencies. A fat jar becomes useful for deploying the final application.